# trying to make IOS standard ui to be in my language

Tags: ios, button, user-interface

Im writing A none en App and i want my standard ui to be in my language, buttons like "edit", "Done" and so on can any boddy help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **info.plist** file set **Localization native development region** to your language